# Why was this flag to migrate a MSE question to MSO declined?

Tags: support, flags, meta, migration, declined-flags

I custom-flagged a [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348120/336163) by a user asking why their Stack Overflow account had been deleted. It was receiving "only applicable to one specific site" closevotes and seemed like a legitimate question - fairly specific, not whiny, not a rant, etc., but a genuine attempt to find out what had happened, so it seemed to be a reasonable candidate for migration.

The flag was declined:

> This post is about the OP's Stack Overflow account, and so belongs on Meta Stack Overflow. Could you please migrate it there? – Robert Columbia 16 hours ago   declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

What specifically was bad about my flag? It occurred to me that maybe the moderator in question is trying to hint that I should have *voted* to migrate the question, but there are no user-accessible migration paths from MSE, so migration *necessarily* requires the intervention of a moderator.

Answer (score 7):

[According to a Stack Overflow moderator](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348120/my-account-on-stack-overflow-seems-to-have-been-removed#comment1164815_348120), their account has been suspended on Stack Overflow. That means they're not *allowed* to post on (Meta) Stack Overflow, and migrating the question might even fail. I'm not sure about the timeline between your flag and that comment, but whenever I see somebody posting about a removed account, I consider that scenario as a possibility.

That doesn't really rhyme with the decline reason, but it does explain why the post isn't being migrated.

Answer (score 4):

Quite simply... There's not much an SO mod can do about a deleted account. You would need staff to take a look. While they can clarify, account deletions are probably something that needs to be handled delicately

SO mods were aware from the comments - so migrating it wouldn't help visibility.

As such MSE mod intervention wasn't needed, and I'm unsure what the benefit of migration would be.